# Display Photo in Android App from Server

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

There is no issue if I display only Image on any `Activity` as I will convert Image to `Bitmap` in `doInBackGround()`.
But what If I am using `Custom ListView` and I want to display Image on each Item ?
I am using `adapter.setViewBinder` for this. But issue is that I can't use it in `doInBackground()` so I need to use in `onPostExecute()` and this is the big problem. Now, if there are more images then app will freeze for sometime till all images convert into `Bitmap`.

How to prevent this issue and complete all process in `doInBackground()` only ?

**My Code :**

```
adapter.setViewBinder(new SimpleAdapter.ViewBinder() {
    @Override
    public boolean setViewValue(View view, Object data, String textRepresentation) {

        if (view.getId() == R.id.imgHotelPhoto) {
            String Photo = data.toString();

            try {
                url_Hotelhoto = new URL("" + WebsiteURL"/images/HotelSmallPhoto/" + Photo + "");
            } catch (MalformedURLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                bmp_HotelPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url_Hotelhoto.openConnection().getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            ((ImageView) view).setImageBitmap(bmp_HotelPhoto);

            return true;
            }

        return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: my suggestion is don't use asynctask when you deal with something that will take unexpected amount of time, things like response from server instead use handler and post message to it. if you don't know how handler works let me know or search in google for examples

Comment: @VilenMelkumyan, I have checked Play Store and found that In app list, it shows Images one bye one as it loads. Can we implement it in our app ? If you have any good tutorial or example then give me reference.

Comment: check this out https://github.com/thest1/LazyList

Comment: @VilenMelkumyan, thank you. Let me check and understand it.